# javascript vuejs object array returning only one item in the loop

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

I am trying to iterate over an array of objects instead its returning only one item here is the code:

```
setAll(){
  var result =this.cart;
  for (var key in result) {
    var obj = result[key];
  }
  return obj.price;
}
```

and the test data

```
 [ { "id": 5, "price": 3200, "quantity": 8, "name": "juice" }, { "id": 6, 
  "price": 300, "quantity": 6, "name": "rice" }, { "id": 8, "price": "100", 
  "quantity": 1, "name": "water" }, { "id": 7, "price": "4500", "quantity": 
   1, "name": "meat" } ]
```

Comment: What is the end result you want here? Do you want to return an array of all of the objects' prices? like `[3200, 300, 100, 4500]`?

Comment: It'll be much easier to answer this with a bit more information; nothing apart from your title tells us that you're using Vue, for example.
If you provide a bit more information about what you're trying to do, it'll be easier for other to help you achieve that.

Comment: I want to return only values with prices using vuejs

Comment: Right now its only returning one price item

Comment: You should use `prices = cart.map(({price}) => +price);` to get all prices from the `cart` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
          setAll(){
          var result =this.cart;
          var res=Object.keys(result).map(function(key){
            return parseInt(result[key].price);
          });
          return res;

         },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the array and only returning the last object. This code:

```
for (var key in result) {
   var obj = result[key];
}
```

does nothing other than set `obj` to the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `object` will be set to its value from the last iteration through the loop, and you will return the price of that object only.

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: I thought about that, but it does also contain the information in the answer above it.

Comment: Ok, extracted a comment from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

your function replace to

```
setAll(){
  return this.cart.map(({ price }) => +price);
}
```

i am write [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pqj4811/2/) example for your question

Comment: using this function I am getting babel-loader error

Comment: screenshot working result https://monosnap.com/file/sRFX1SzfateAf0ISy0clfUSIxy9YMX

Comment: @IgorOgnichenko edit your answer adding your jsfiddle instead of commenting. Try to make a readable, simple and complete answer